# Can you wear magical boots/gloves/gauntlets while wearing plate armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, equipment, armor, dnd-adventurers-league

In Adventurers League, can you wear magical boots/gloves/gauntlets while wearing plate armor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, you can add anything but another armor

While not as explicitly as in previous editions, magic items occupy distinct *slots*. A boot occupies your *feet* slot, a hat occupies your *head* slot, and so on.

This is indirectly mentioned in the [Multiple Items of the Same Kind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/magic-items#MultipleItemsoftheSameKind) section of the rules:

> [...] A character can’t normally wear more than **one pair of footwear, one pair of gloves or gauntlets, one pair of bracers, one suit of armor, one item of headwear, and one cloak**. You can make exceptions; a character might be able to wear a circlet under a helmet, for example, or be able to layer two cloaks.

Your armor, regardless of its appearance, occupies your *armor* slot, but does not prevent wearing unrelated footwear or even bracers.

Historically, plate armor came with helmet and boots, but D&D is not a simulationist game.
Consequently, you can match any armor with any helmet, glove or boot, but you cannot just wear the breastplate part of your half plate when you want to avoid disadvantage on stealth.

Comment: I would say that last part is up to the DM. Nothing explicitly forbids you from dismantling your items.

Comment: Plate armor's description specifically includes a helmet. I see that replacing the helmet with with something that has similar protective qualities would be fine (Helmet of Brillance), but I've a hard time believing that any replacement will do (Hat of Wizardry). Also probably for magic plate armor you may have to wear the full suit...

Comment: @Szega every part is up to the DM, as I wrote, the rules are not as explicit as in previous editions. Which is very unfortunate for AL

Comment: The multiple items of the same kind is specifically referring to multiple magic items of the same kind, the example provided is two magic cloaks.

Answer (score 5):

### Maybe

The Player's Handbook is clear that:

> Plate consists of shaped, interlocking metal plates to cover the entire body. A suit of plate includes gauntlets, heavy leather boots, a visored helmet, and thick layers of padding underneath the armor. Buckles and straps distribute the weight over the body.

The armor you are wearing already includes gauntlets, boots, and a helmet. ([Another question on this site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119053/41726) tackles the force-of-rule that these descriptions have on available armor in the Adventurer's League)

The Dungeon Master's Guide describes what to do in this situation:

> Use common sense to determine whether more than one of a given kind of magic item can be worn. A character can’t normally wear more than one pair of footwear, one pair of gloves or gauntlets, one pair of bracers, one suit of armor, one item of headwear, and one cloak. You can make exceptions; a character might be able to wear a circlet under a helmet, for example, or be able to layer two cloaks.

However, this rule only applies to wearing "more than one of a given kind of magic item" and says nothing about wearing a magical gauntlet, with the mundane gauntlets of plate armor. With regard to that scenario, the rules are silent. You will have to ask a GM how they will be interpreting these rules to cover the ability to wear armor pieces of both mundane and magic quality.

*Note: you should be able to wear gloves under your gauntlets, or a circlet under your helmet, or [slippers under your boots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/116117/41726) with GM permission*